# General ledger and accounts payable data model

Tags: database-design

I am looking for industry standard logical data model of general ledger and accounts payable.

Are there any readily available accounting data models?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I learned the data model while I learned bookkeeping.  If Google does not give you an answer, that might be the way to go.

The most basic ledger is 3 tables: Accounts, Batches, and Transactions.  All transactions must be in a batch.  Some people make two columns for debit and credit, I always did one column, with Debits and credits having opposite signs.

Payables is also very simple.  At its heart is a table of vendors and a table of vouchers/invoices.  Finally a table of checks generated.  Unlike purchasing, payables does not require linking to inventory or any detail on the voucher, making it quite simple.

After that, embellish to taste :)

Comment: .."All transactions must be in a batch."  Can you elaborate on this a bit?  Are you referring to a maker/checker scenario where transactions originally are recorded into the Batch before being "approved" and then permanently recorded as Transactions?

Comment: @swisscheese: To initiate any activity in the ledger, you create a batch header, and then put individual debits/credits into the batch.  So it means all individual debits/credits are part of this batch.  The batch may have a description, a user who entered it, and of course the transaction date.

Comment: @KenDowns Would you please show an example of accounts, batches and transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Core GL Transactional Tables:

- LEDGER
- JOURNAL_HEADER
- JOURNAL_LINE

The journals are validated before posting to the LEDGER table.

Core AP Tables:

- INVOICE
- CHECK
- VENDOR